# Replace arguments in ArgumentParser

Tags: python, argparse

I create a `argparse.ArgumentParser` instance from a config file, adding arguments from the name and value of entries.

Later in my code I want to specifically set some arguments, lets say `--hidden_size` is one of them.

When I run

```py
parser.add_argument('--hidden_size', type=int, metavar='N', help='Hidden size')
```

I get `argparse.ArgumentError: argument --hidden_size: conflicting option string: --hidden_size`.

What would be the easiest way to replace an entry?
Ideally, it should look something like this:

```py
arg = parser['--hidden_size']
parser.add_argument('--hidden_size', type=int, metavar='N', default=arg.default, help='Hidden size')
```

However, neither can I access the argument by subscripting the parser, nor can I replace an argument with the method `add_argument` and the same name.
How would this be done?

Comment: read the docs regarding the conflict handler.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#conflict-handler - with 'resolve', the handler makes a new argument, removing the conflicting flag(s) from the old.  But if you are just changing some parameters like `default` or `type`, @chapner's approach is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hack because it relies on hidden attribute of an `ArgumentParser`:

```py
import argparse

def lookup(par, arg):
    for action in par._actions:
        if arg in action.option_strings:
            return action
    raise ValueError(f"{arg} not found")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--hidden_size")


try:
    # Lookup --hidden_size and update
    action = lookup(parser, "--hidden_size")
    action.type = int
    action.metavar = "N"
    action.help = "Hidden size"
except ValueError:
    # Lookup failed, add new
    parser.add_argument('--hidden_size', type=int, metavar='N', help='Hidden size')
```

Comment: `par._actions` might technically be 'hidden', but it's a useful attribute to be aware of, especially when you do more advanced things.

Comment: In the `argparse.py` file, `_Actions_Container._check_actions` method (and following) check for conflicts and either raise an error or attempt to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The object representing the argument is returned by `add_argument`; you can set its `default` attribute at any time, and the current value will be used by `parse_args` when necessary.

```
>>> import argparse
>>> p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> x = p.add_argument('--foo', type=int)
>>> p.parse_args()
Namespace(foo=None)
>>> x.default = 9
>>> p.parse_args()
Namespace(foo=9)
```